# Why did Voldemort have Harry Potter's name entered in the Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter

The reason given by the book seems to be so that Harry can touch the Triwizard Cup, secretly turned into a portkey by Barty Crouch the younger, and be transported to Voldemort. But if any object can be turned into a portkey, why on earth would Voldemort choose an object that would require so many hoops to jump through in order for Harry to be the first to touch it? It's  the whole premise of the book, but it seems like a lot of wasted effort on Voldemort's part.